# Should a Java Boolean be used for ternary (3-state) logic?

Tags: java, programming-practices, boolean

I'm trying to make a basic cache of a boolean value, and I did it like such:

```java
private Boolean _valueCache = null;
private boolean getValue() {
    try {
        if (_valueCache == null) { // if cache was never filled
            return _valueCache = getReader().getMyBooleanProperty(); // fill it and return the new value
        }
        return _valueCache; // else, return the cache
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) { // getReader() returned null
        return false; // that return may not be null in the future, so set nothing
    }
}
```

**Does this go against best practices?** (letting a `Boolean` have 3 values: `true`, `false`, and `null`) I only want to cache this value, so I don't want to make an entire custom HashMap that mimics this behavior with a get-or-default method. That said, I've never done a cache this small so I don't know the downsides to it.

**To clarify**, I meant "ternary" as in "3-state", as opposed to "binary" as in "2-state". Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: See this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152094/null-pointers-vs-null-object-pattern and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij is NOP possible in Java? As far as I know, there's no way to `myMethod(o)` branch to different method definitions at runtime (like `myMethod(Object o)` vs `myMethod(null o)`), or even to make a method take a `null`. Also, the provided question's answer mentions `methodA()->methodB()`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` in Java if `methodA()` returns `null`.

Comment: Related reading: **[Why use a bool over more domain specific abstractions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/275011/22815)**. While the question is not a duplicate, the answers do help address what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What about FILE_NOT_FOUND ?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Comment: The overarching question is IMHO: Should you ever catch a `NullPointerException`. The answer is : *NO*.

Comment: @Marco13 Why? If you think you have a good answer to this question, you should post it 

Comment: @BenLeggiero The intention was not to answer the question. That's why it is only a *comment*, and not an answer. For the NPE part, I'd point to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265940/when-is-it-ok-to-catch-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not doing ternary logic, you're just using `null` as a placeholder for a missing value that happens to be of type `Boolean`. (Not having `true` nor `false` isn't quite the same as having one of the two but not knowing which.) Using `null` this way is a fairly common practice, but [I wouldn't call it a good one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing).

It's unlikely to cause you problems in this particular case because it's only used internally within a very small scope, but in general you would want to use [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead. Since any non-primitive variable could have `null`, it's very difficult to keep track of it in a large code base. The easiest way to avoid the issue is to not use `null` in the first place.

Comment: The `Optional` class looks promising! If only I weren't forced to use Java 1.6...

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has an `Optional` implementation as well and should work with 1.6. It's also not hard to implement yourself.

Answer (score 2):

While using null or using an Optional are reasonable choices, one more option would be to add an explicit second field, `boolean _hasBeenRead`.  Your code would look like

```
private boolean getValue() {
    if (_hasBeenRead)
       return _valueCache;

    else {
       // read the value and, if successful, set both _hasBeenRead and _valueCache.
    }
}
```

Some would consider this more explicit and therefore clearer.  Especially if you are using older style Java without new fangled goodies like Optional.

p.s. Whatever you do, consider whether this method need be synchronized, if the variables need to be volatile, etc...

Comment: Good point about the `volatile` and `synchronized` status! This is for Android, so I'm not entirely sure what threads will need this or when.

Answer (score -3):

The  tenary logic for this should be

```
private Boolean _valueCache = null;
private boolean getValue() { 
         Boolean readerValue = getReader() == null ? false : reader.getMyBooleanProperty();
         _valueCache = _valueCache == null  ? readerValue : _valueCache; 
         return _valueCache;

   }
```

By the way, what is the use of the NullPointer exception handled, Does the getReader() return null, Runtime exceptions like this are also not advisable

Comment: <sarcasm mode on>That line of code is too short - somebody might actually understand it.</sarcasm mode on>

Comment: Thanks for your input! Sorry, I wasn't clear. I don't need help on how to use the ternary operators `?:`, but on whether this 3-state `Boolean` is a good idea.

Comment: Also, the `getReader()` method (not made/controlled/modifiable by me) contains a conditional `throw new NullPointerException()` in it, so the `try`/`catch` is necessary, anyway.