# Why F#, Rust and others use Option type instead of nullable types like C# 8 or TypeScript?

Tags: language-design, null

AFAIK, `Option` type will have runtime overhead, while nullable types won't, because `Option` time is an enum (consuming memory).

Why not just mark optional references as optional, then the compiler can follow code execution and find whenever it can't more be `null`?

**Edit**: I see I was misunderstood. I understand and agree with the advantages of avoiding null pointers. I'm not talking about arbitrary pointers that accept `null`. I'm only asking why not use compile-time metadata, like C# 8's nullable reference types and TypeScript with strict null checks, where default pointers can't be null and there's a special syntax (mostly `?`) to indicate a pointer that can accept null.

**Edit 2**:

Also, `Some` is strange, in my opinion. Implicit conversion would be better. But that a language feature and not relevant.

Comment: The memory that `Option` consumes is inconsequential compared to the benefit it provides.

Comment: Not all Option implementations take more memory.

Comment: [The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/)

Comment: @Telastyn Can you explain why?

Comment: "Whilst the name is better, it also has the disadvantage that check against null become tedious and harder-to-read." – As I wrote in my answer, *if you are checking an `Option`, you are doing it wrong*. `Option` is a container and thus iterable and traversable, it is also a monad, and thus also an applicative functor and a functor, which means it can be mapped and flatMapped over. You first example should be [`v.unwrap_or(0)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) the second could (for example) simply be …

Comment: … [v.unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap), which will panic on its own, or (not equivalent but IMO a better choice) [`v.ok_or("Unexpected None")`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Agreed. Removed that claim

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The Rust compiler is able to optimize the memory used by `enum`s to use empty niches in types. In particular, since references cannot be null in Rust, `Option<&T>` will have the same size as a pointer.

Comment: This question is grounds for serious religious debates. The difference is one of history and legacy, since nullables with static null-checking (as seen in Kotlin) are functionally equivalent to Option types in all ways except composability.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/373751/206652

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The purpose of *Null Tracking* in general (of which Nullable Types are only one of many different forms), is to somehow regain a modicum of safety (and sanity) in languages that have null references.

*If* you have the chance to eliminate null references altogether, that is a *much better solution* since the problems that null references cause *simply will not exist* in the first place. Sir Tony Hoare has famously said that he considers inventing the Null Reference his "Billion Dollar Mistake", which is actually a quite conservative estimate on the total costs that null references have caused until today. If even the person who invented them considers them a mistake, why would you willingly put them in a language?

C# has them because, well, they probably didn't know any better, and now they can't get rid of them because of backwards-compatibility. TypeScript has them because its semantics are based on ECMAScript's, which has them.

The *real* beauty of an `Option` type, though, is that it is isomorphic to a collection that can only hold from zero to one elements. Dealing with collections is one of the most important parts of programming, and thus every language in the world has powerful collections libraries. And you can apply all of the work that has gone into collections also to `Option` types.

For example, if you want to execute an action with an option, you *don't* need to check whether it is defined! Every collection library on the planet has a way of iterating over a collection and executing an action for each element. Now, what does "executing an action for each element" mean for an `Option`? Well, if there is no element, then no action is executed. And if there is one element, then the action is executed once with that element.

In other words, `foreach` acts *exactly* like a `NULL` check! You can just blindly do

```scala
mightExistOrMightNot.foreach(println)
```

and it will print out the value contained in the `Option` if it exists and do nothing if it doesn't exist. The same applies when you want to perform a computation with the value. Every collections library on the planet has a way of iteration over a collection and transforming each element. Again, for an `Option` "transforming each element" translates to "transform the value or do nothing". So you can just do

```scala
val squared: Option[Int] = mightExistOrMightNot.map(_ ** 2)
```

Also, collections libraries have ways to flatten nested collections. Imagine you have a long chain of references, each of which could be `NULL`, and you wanted to access the last reference in that chain. With nested `Option`s, you just write

```scala
longListOfReferences.flatten
```

And if you want to get a value out of an `Option`, then you can simply write

```scala
mightExistOrMightNot.getOrElse(42)
```

and you will either get the value inside the option if it exists, or a default value of your choosing if it doesn't.

The *only* reason, really, for you to explicitly check for the existence of an `Option` is if you want to do something *completely different* in case the value is missing.

It turns out that `Option` is actually even more than "just" a collection. It is a *monad*. Languages like C#, Scala, and Haskell have built in syntax sugar for working with monads, and they have powerful libraries for working with monads. I will not go into details about what it means to be a monad, but e.g. one of the advantages is that there are some specific mathematical laws and properties associated with monads, and one can exploit those properties.

The fact that Java's `Optional` is not implemented as a monad, not even as a collection, is a significant design flaw, and I think is partially to blame for people not understanding the advantages of `Option`s, simply because some of those advantages cannot be realized with Java's `Optional`.

There is also a more philosophical reason for choosing an `Option` type over `NULL` references. We can call this "language democracy". There is a major difference between those two: `NULL` references are a *language feature* whereas `Option` is a *library type*.

*Everybody* can write a library type, but only the language designer can write a language feature. That means that if for my code, I need to handle the absence of values in a slightly different manner, I can write a `MyOption`. But I cannot write a `MYNULL` reference without changing the language semantics and thus the compiler (or, for a language like C, C++, Java, Go, ECMAScript, Python, Ruby, PHP with multiple implementations, *every single compiler and interpreter that exists, has existed, and will ever exist*).

The more the language designer moves out of the language into libraries, the more the programmers can tailor the language (really, the library) to their needs.

Also, the more the language designer moves out of the language into libraries, the more the compiler writers are forced to make library code fast. If a compiler writer figures out some clever trick to make `NULL` references fast, that doesn't help our hypothetical programmer who has written their own abstraction. But if a compiler writer figures out some clever trick to make `Option` fast, it is highly likely the same trick will also apply to `MyOption` (and `Try`, `Either`, `Result`, and possibly even every collection).

Take Scala, for example. Unfortunately, because it is designed to interoperate and integrate deeply with the host environment (the Java platform, the ECMAScript platform, there is also an abandoned CLI implementation), it has `null` references and exceptions. But, it also has the `Option` type which replaces the former and `Try` which replaces the latter. And `Try` first appeared in a library of helpers released by Twitter. It was only later added to the standard library. Such innovation is much harder to do with language features.

I can write my own Scala `Option` type, and I don't need to change the compiler for it:

```scala
sealed trait Option[+A] extends IterableOnce[A]:
  override def iterator: Iterator[A]
  override def knownSize: Int

  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
  def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B]
  // … and so on

final case class Some[+A](value: A) extends Option[A]:
  override def iterator = collection.Iterator.single(value)
  override val isEmpty = false
  
  override val knownSize = 1
  override def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B) = value
  override def foreach[U](f: A => U) = f(value)
  override def map[B](f: A => B) = Some(f(value))
  // … and so on

case object None extends Option[Nothing]:
  override def iterator = collection.Iterator.empty
  override val isEmpty = true

  override val knownSize = 0
  override def getOrElse[B](default: => B) = default
  override def foreach[U](f: Nothing => U) = ()
  override def map[B](f: Nothing => B) = None
  // … and so on

@main def test = Some(23).foreach(println)
```

[Try it out here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/legxp04eRCembpW6xzbfhQ/4).

Comment: Why? Why not include null references naturally and just perform compile-time checks? If you're talking about framework support, then your _hardware_ prefers null (because null is just zero pointer whereas `Option` type is enum, and AFAIK, the CPU performs checks for zero pointer when dereferencing).

Comment: @Chayim Indeed, a language like Rust will do that. Using Option on a reference type will [compile to a single pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16515488/2854284). An extra word for storing the Option's enum value is only use for ints, floats, etc. But with the Option type you use them the same way, and the compiler handles making it performant and safe for you.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Collections operations are some of the most important ones for programming. If a language wants to be "fast", it must make it possible to implement high-performance collections. Since `Option` is isomorphic to a collection, once you have high-performance collections, you automatically also have high-performance `Option`. And, these performance optimizations apply *generally*, not specifically to `NULL` references.

Comment: C# has no Option type, why are you talking about it like there is?

Comment: As answered to many other questions, nullability isn't the error. Making it standard is, especially without a way to opt out.

Comment: @masm64 because C# 8 introduced Nullable Reference Types which OP is referring to in the question.

Comment: @masm64: Who you mean by "you"? I cannot find a single instance on this entire page, not in the question, not in any of the answers, not in any of the comments, of someone claiming or even just implying that C# has an `Option` type. That said, `Option` is a *library* type, so saying that "a language has an `Option` type" doesn't even make sense. And articles like https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1510/maybe-monad-csharp prove that C# can easily support an `Option` type.

Comment: "Languages like C#, Scala, and Haskell have built in syntax sugar for working with monads" - please elaborate on C#'s syntactical sugar regarding monads.

Comment: @IanKemp: LINQ Query Expressions were added in C# 3.0. They were made to look like XQuery queries, which is why the names of the operations look unfamiliar, but they are exactly the monad operations: `SELECT` desugars to `Select` which is `map`, `SelectMany` is `flatMap` (and nested `SELECT` expressions desugar to calls to `flatMap`), and so on.

Comment: I tend to consider the ECMAScript a slightly different case, I always thought that using `null` to indicate the end of the prototype chain a clever idea (maybe I'm wrong?), but the language actually has `null` AND `undefined`. It seems that in the context of the discussion, we are talking about the latter, not the former. What typescript did with ECMAScript is probably a bad example, I'm not that found on how typescript did things for many reasons..

Comment: Tony Hoare did not say null references was the billion dollar mistake. Hoare said that making *all* references nullable was the billon dollar mistake. C# 8 and Typescript are solving this with non-nullable reference types.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Seriously you think C# has references (that allow nulls) because "they [the language designers] didn't know any better"?  I suddenly realize I have to devalue all of your answers.

Comment: Nice answer - there's one additional conceptual benefit to Optional<T> instead of just preventing nulls - It allows you to be flexibly about WHERE and WHEN you handle the null case. You can pass an Optional by reference and handle it's non-existence where appropriate, instead of being forced to handle it at the site where it's instantiated.

Comment: The C# designers wanted non-nullable references in C# from the get go. They just couldn't find a way to do it well, in the time (and budget) constraints they had to work with. Just think about where null references crop up by default - arrays, structs, fields etc. With .NET guaranteeing pre-zeroed data, it's quite hard to avoid nulls, especially in edge cases like half-initialized objects (don't forget you can _always_ leak `this` from a constructor).

Comment: Damn you must be fun at parties Jörg. "It turns out that Option is actually even more than "just" a collection. It is a monad. Languages like C#, Scala, and Haskell have built in syntax sugar for working with monads" This sentence of yours is ambiguous, that is all that I am saying.

Comment: It might be a billion dollar mistake but it's also a billion dollar gain. It is not easy to create a language without null references that also is efficient and general purpose. The fix for the "mistake" is not clear.

Comment: @usr Are you sure about that? I mean, we have numerous languages that somehow manage to avoid having every type potentially null, yet are also as efficient (or potentially more efficient with significantly fewer null checks) as languages that do force every type to be potentially null. Rust proves that `Option<&T>` can be *exactly* as efficient as a potentially null `*T` in C++, while providing compile time guarantees that C++ can't.

Comment: @8bittree maybe you're right. I was thinking of the case of allocating an array of references. There either has to be some default value or some way to ensure that elements are not accessed before initialization. I don't think that can be done in general.

Comment: @usr Sticking with Rust because of familiarity: `vec![Option::default(); n]` creates a heap allocated, grow-able array of `n` `None`s. Alternatively, `vec::with_capacity(n)` will create a similar array, but with `0` elements, and which can store `n` elements before needing to reallocate. Depending on the situation, with the latter, you might be able to just use the plain reference without the `Option` wrapper.

Comment: @8bittree: The only way to eliminate the need for nullable references is to require that all reads of objects are preceded by writes.  For some kinds of objects that makes sense, but for arrays not so much.  There are many situations where a programmer may know that code will never read any element of an array that hasn't yet been written, but where proving that by static analysis would be impractical.  Further, the places where null references wreak the most havoc are in C implementations that allow expressions that add offsets to null pointers to yield invalid pointers that aren't null.

Comment: With regards to C# containing nullable references: "because they [the language designers] didn't know any better" would be more accurately phrased as "because C# started out as a clone of Java, created to avoid [lawsuits from Sun Microsystems](https://www.cnet.com/news/sun-microsoft-settle-java-suit/). (Microsoft was sued because it copied Java and was extending it in incompatible ways to break "write once run anywhere", in deliberate violation of the licensing contract that Microsoft had signed not to do that.) Java was implemented that way in order to seem not too alien to C++ programmers."

Comment: For "because they [the C# language designers] didn't know any better", remember that the first versions did not have generics, which make it yet harder.

Answer (score 34):

## NULL is Overloaded.

NULL simultaneously means:

- This variable has not been initialised
- This variable has been initialised, but does not point to a valid object, and as such is invalid
- This variable has been initialised, but does not point to a valid object, and this is perfectly valid
- This variable has been cleared and should never be used again
- This is the magic third logic value

*I'm quite likely missing a few definitions.*

So which meaning does this NULL represent?

## The Solution

Well that depends on the meaning being ascribed to NULL.

Optional works in the sense of knowing the state of initialisation, and that not being initialised is valid.

A NullObject works in that it conforms to an interface a can be used anywhere the normal object can be while doing some sort of default "nullish" behaviour.

A Trinary Logic Value works best when NULL is the third wheel in a logic system.

There are other solutions, but there isn't any reason to favour one solution over another across the board.

## Language Support

At this level it boils down to how the type system is formulated.

Some systems prefer to have some relatively complex primitives. Usually these primitives are reflections of either an historical implementation, or of some underlying platform constraint. In the case of C# it inherited much of is syntax and semantic style from C/C++/Java. This is reflected in the fact that all object references are default nullable, and all values are default non-nullable.

In the case of C# the language, the type system is sufficiently complex to support an `Optional` type allowing value types to gain a nullable state, but there isn't a trivial way to remove nullability from the object references.

Some systems prefer to have very simple primitive types, and rely on a powerful type composition system to create the desired behaviours. In these languages a C# nullable Reference might look like `def cs_reference(T) => NULL | T`. The Optional pattern makes more sense though in these languages: `def Option(T) => T[0..1]`. Its an array/list/sequence of 0 or 1 element.

Using a sequence/array concept leverages our understanding of empty, and has one element. Its directly compatible with anything that accepts the sequence/array concept. And its recomposable within the type system `T[0..1][0..1]`. Where as `cs_reference` isn't `cs_reference(cs_reference(T)) == NULL | T`.

Comment: Nice. But I'm not fully agree. Uninitialized variables are not allowed to use in modern languages. I can't think a way an object can be invalid in modern languages (in C++ for example it can if the constructor threw an exception). <continuation in next comment...>

Comment: <continuation from previous comment> Third reason is just like `Option`. Cleared and should not be used again - again this is favor of languages like C++ where you can invoke the destructor manually etc.. Magic value - well, **third** magic value (I can enumerate more: `true` and `false` are too many times). There are 0 and 1. And well, an experienced programmer will use constants. Language won't disallow use of ` and 0...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Any language capable of call the underlying platform API's, or embedding unsafe access such as via C# unsafe pointer, must be aware of invalid objects, and frankly that includes "modern" languages. But more importantly and to my point validity isn't just a language level concept, try calling a method on a null valued object in C#, what happens? Its a perfectly valid (and defined behaviour) but as far as the programmer is concerned this is an invalid object at this point in time. If it were valid, the call would occur as expected. The null would be valid if an `if` handled it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman True an experienced programmer will use constants when they have the luxury. Embedded systems don't always have that affordance, and neither do high-performance systems that must squeeze (such as the python run time which performs pointer tagging). I also feel you overly discount the volume of inexperienced programmers, and their tendency to prove how much code golf they can achieve.

Comment: Unsafe code is, ah, unsafe. By design it does not prevent you from accessing low-lever API, and with power comes responsibility. Programmers usually don't use unsafe code, and if they do, they separate it to other classes/modules/packages/dlls/etc.. Also I don't understand why embedded or real-time system can't have constants, especially since compilers nowadays are smart enough to inline compile-time constants when that makes sense.

Comment: And about validity, if the object access triggers `NullReferenceException` (or `NullPointerException`, `TypeError`, ...) that means unexpected null. This is exactly the situation that nullable types I'm talking about (and `Option` types, of course) are here to prevent

Comment: And even rust has unsafe context when you can dereference null. Such contexts are exist (in both C# and Rust, as well as other languages) not to do something you can't with the language, and usually even not to achieve raw performance, but to deal with C-and-similar APIs. You can't call Windows or Linux function that takes a pointer with an `Option` type.

Comment: I disagree with "Null is a problem because it's overloaded" specifically because Optional has exactly the same problem. Therefore this is not a reason to prefer Optional to Null.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No, Rust's `unsafe` blocks do not allow you to dereference `NULL` (usually the pointer to the memory location `0x00000000`). They allow you to circumvent a few compiler checks, including the restriction on dereferencing arbitrary pointers (which could potentially be `0`, aka `NULL`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman And `Option<&ptr>` in Rust is the same size as `&ptr` and `usize`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `NullReferenceException` means attempted to dereference a Null. That makes no statement about whether the program considers that a valid state or not, just that the language considers the program malformed. The prevention for such in a language would not be `Optional` but non-nullable reference types, or value types - allowing the program to preclude the invalid state. `Optional` provides the converse, allowing a program to indicate that NULL is a valid state, and with appropriate language support ensure that the case is suitably handled precluding the language from throwing.

Comment: @MooingDuck In the C# case this is correct. But in a more powerful type savy language `Optional` indicates to the compiler that both cases must be handled gracefully by the program. Such languages will fail to compile a program that cannot be verified to handle the NULL case, and the Non-Null case. Thus it isn't possible for such a program to dereference NULL.

Comment: @Kain0_0: Sure, I don't disagree with that. That's a valid argument for Optional being better than null.  But "Null is a problem because it's overloaded" is not a valid argument.  They're separate arguments, and only the first is valid. And the valid one isn't stated explicitly in this answer. It's only vaguely hinted at in the final section.

Comment: @MooingDuck Right, rereading my answer I can see how you come away with "NULL is bad because its Overloaded". My point wasn't that its bad because its overloaded, otherwise most human languages would be bad. I was trying to illustrate that the compiler can't just guess the writers intention here, the meaning can be so easily overloaded. But thank you for pointing out where I can improve my answers.

Comment: @Kain0_0: Considering the opening section is "Null is overloaded", it's _really_ easy to reach that interpretation. Also, because literally everything up to " powerful type composition system to create the desired behaviours." also applies to explaining why "Optional" is bad. :D

Answer (score 24):

Much of the angst over nulls are due to languages where *every* reference type is nullable by default. But this is not an issue for Typescript or C# 8 so lets disregard that.

There are two basic approaches to how to optional values are represented:

- A distinct container type (the Option type) which contain zero or one
  instances of the actual value.
- A union type of the original type with a "sentinel" value, `null`, which indicate the lack of a value. In Typescript it would be declared as a `(actualType | null)` type union. (Or shortened as `actualType?`, but the the explicit union makes it clearer what is going on.)

On the face of it they seem similar, but a significant difference is that containers nest but type unions don't. An option can contain another option as its value, but `((actualType | null) | null)` is just the same as `(actualType | null)`.

For example consider a dictionary. The lookup function could return an option: `Nothing` if the key does not exist, otherwise `Some value`. This will work with any type of value. If the values in the dictionary are themselves options, the lookup will just return an option where the value (if any) is itself an option.

But what if we instead use null to represent a missing value? Then the lookup function can return a value or a null, but there is no way to distinguish between if the null means the key did not exist or the key *did* exist but the associated value was null. You lose what could be important information.

Dictionaries are just an example, the problem arise anywhere you have a data-structure with multiple levels of optional elements. Nullable types prevent polymorphism: code can't manipulate data of an unknown type generically, it has to treat nullable and non-nullable types differently.

You can see how C# has to use awkward workarounds in the Dictionary interface. Either it throws an Exception (eww!) if the key is not found, or with TryGetValue() it returns a boolean indicating if the key is found and then the value (or null) on an `out` parameter. This is pretty ugly and it doesn't scale and is not composable. Option types solves this elegantly, and in a way that is consistent with the rest of the language.

Comment: The pitfalls of forced reference-types and forced nullability. Not a downside of having null/none/empty.

Comment: There are a handful of solutions to this problem with dictionaries. What is appropriate depends on the language. One solution is to return a pair of values:  (answer OR null) AND (did we find something). Common lisp's hash tables do this.

Comment: @Riley: It is not a specifically a problem with dictionaries, that is just an example. It is a problem with any data structure with can contain multiple levels of optional values. Returning a pair is better than using null since you can still nest them.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It is not a question of forced nullability. You have the same issue in languages where nullability is optional. As soon as you have nested optionals you have the issue.

Comment: How often do you *really* need to nest optionality? I've found it useful in one case when I needed to distinguish 'uninitialized' from 'missing value', but it's rare to need that distinction and it's easily remedied by one-off dataclasses with a single nullable field. It's an awful lot of overhead and verbosity for a feature I don't need 95% of the time.

Comment: @Beefster: "one-off dataclasses with a single nullable field" is just an ad-hoc option type. Surely writing your own ad-hoc option type every time you need it is more overhead and verbosity than just using a standard.

Comment: @Beefster It's not that common to explicitly nest optionality, but it's very common that it happens because two separate pieces of code use it, and they happen to be used together. You can't have generic polymorphism (code that can process data without knowing what it is, for example a collection) with nullable types.

Comment: in practice the container solution tends to be monadic which means that 'nested Options' get flattened there too

Answer (score 11):

Pass me a null and I have to check for null to avoid throwing an exception.

Pass me an option, or an empty collection, or a null object, and I can avoid needing the check. I can use it the same as the other valid values and watch it quietly do nothing.

Use this wisely and it makes code easier to read.

Insist on checking for null and checks clutter code and confusion is caused because now some nulls are meant to cause exceptions and other aren’t.

Some might argue to fail early, but that could have happened before the null even got here. Pass me a null and you have to hope I know what you wanted done with it.

If you believe in fail early and want a process halting exception thrown just throw it. If you don’t need anything cleaned up don’t throw exceptions at me expecting me to silence them and don’t pass me nulls expecting me to check them.

It is possible to design complex systems that don’t even permit the use of null. Instead we design objects that do nothing. If that means consuming a little memory so I can point at the kind of nothing I need then so be it. It’s not like there are that many kinds.

Comment: Yes. Many people argue "What's the difference whether I have an `if` statement checking for `NULL` or an `if` statement checking for `None`", but the point is, if you are checking your `Option`s, *then you are doing it wrong*.

Comment: "Use this wisely and it makes code easier to read". Agreed. Objective-C silently swallows method calls on nil objects, and so apps don't crash, but then they proceed with missing data. However you do it, you do need to ensure that your program has all the data it needs.

"watch it quietly do nothing" and that can be a problem. Fail early, fail fast.

Comment: Pass me a nullable/optional and I have to check for null/empty. It's a shame that non-nullables are most often a retrofit, if they are considered at all.

Comment: Pass me a null and I have to check for null once. Pass me an Option and I have to use `map` on it every time I want to do something interesting. The difference is one of preference. Option is equivalent to a static null check that leverages the type system instead of some other compile-time checking mechanism.

Comment: @Beefster option doesn’t always take on a value at compile time.

Comment: @Beefster You could just extract the wrapped object from the Option, then operate on that, or handle the `None` case the same as you would have if your reference was null. Same effort as a single null check, but with the added benefit that you can't forget to do it.

Comment: @8bittree compile-time checks can *also* make sure you don't forget to check for null. Kotlin does this and additionally offers a much terser syntax than `.map` (in the form of `?.`) that will never call a function. The other difference is that the idiomatic nature of using `Option.map` makes it vastly less obvious what's happening if you've never seen a monad before.

Comment: @Beefster I stand corrected on the compile time checks. But I'm unconvinced by the unfamiliarity of `Option.map`. First, the exact same argument applies to `?.`. Second, `map` is more broadly applicable, as it's usable with any collection, not just `Option`. But that all aside, there's not really any reason you can't implement `?.` or some similar syntax on `Option`. In fact, Rust has `?`. It is somewhat different in that it exits the enclosing function instead of a complete no-op on `None`, plus it also works on `Result`s (and maybe user types, if the trait makes it out of nightly).

Answer (score 11):

Nullable types need 3 states in order to be safe and useful:

- Null.
- Unknown if it is null or not.
- Definitely not null. Safe to assign to a non-nullable.

You can only encode two of those states at runtime in a memory pointer. The third state is determined statically at compile time. The compiler determines from the context that you have done a null check, so you can safely treat it as non-nullable inside that context.

Those types of static checks are a relatively recent invention. They were invented in *response* to options, as a way to pull in the benefits of options without the memory overhead and with a more familiar syntax. So a big part of the reason why more languages don't use statically-checked nullables is because options were invented first.

I think more languages will drift to the statically-checked nullable model over time, but more languages will also drift to the option model, because it has its own advantages.

Options are only one of many types that encode an error/empty state. There is Either, Try, IO, Future, Task, Observable, Validation, and many more, all with their own use cases. It seems very odd to me to give options special treatment in the compiler and leave all the rest in libraries, especially given how common it is to do things like change Option code to Either code when requirements change.

Comment: "Nullable types need 3 states in order to be safe and useful" - I rarely need a third state. Distinction between 'deliberately null' and 'uninitialized' is only needed regularly by the most eccentric javascript programmers.

Comment: If you ever do a `if var == null`, then you are in the second state transitioning to one of the other two. If you never do a null check, you don't need a nullable reference.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Upvoted. It's a little confusing the way you phrased it. Basically state 2 is schrodinger's nullable, and it can be handled reasonably with static analysis.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the 3rd state. It's one of the things Swift does fairly well and why I'm so happy having moved to it from C++. It's also why purely adding your own optional implementations as a library doesn't work nearly as well.

Answer (score 10):

> AFAIK, Option type will have runtime overhead, while nullable types won't, because Option time is an enum (consuming memory).

This is incorrect. Nullables have exactly the same overhead as option types in Rust, and overall the overhead can go either way depending on the language design. You can have option types with no overhead over nullables, and you can have nullables with overhead over option types.

In Rust, `Option<Box<T>>` is represented by a nullable pointer. If anything, `Option` is more efficient than some languages with `null` because `Option` lets you represent optionals as stack based value types, whereas in languages with `null` these optionals need to be heap-allocated so that `null` can be used.

C# and Typescript are garbage collected and almost everything is on the heap. In that sense, `null` exists as a state anyway. On the other hand, Rust is not: most values in Rust are not on the heap, so if you wanted to represent a null state you need an additional bit *anyway*. Which is what `Option` does, and it optimizes the heap case to use null pointers.

Comment: "Nullables have exactly the same overhead as option types." Citation needed. This is not true in all cases for all languages. `option.map { lambda }` also carries more overhead than `if not null { do something }` unless the compiler is smart enough to inline the closures and function calls. That optimization is not something you can count on happening in all cases.

Comment: @Beefster That paragraph begins with "In Rust, […]". The example you gave is not Rust.

Comment: @Toothbrush My objection applies to the sentence immediately *before* that paragraph.

Comment: @beefster updated, I was more saying that it's not clear cut that nullables always have less overhead

Comment: TypeScript is built on top of js, so yes, it's garbage collected. C# is garbage collected too, but has the concept of value types (structs). In fact, we had nullable value types since C# 2, while nullable reference types was introduced in C# 8, and implemented in entirely different strategy. Nullable value types in C# are not heap allocated, and their implementation is similar to Rust's one

Comment: Note that Rust's `Option::map` is considered zero-cost. It would be very surprising if it didn't optimize away.

Comment: @chayim right, so how does the rust version have any more overhead than c#? Either option and nullables have the same overhead, or nullables have a greater overhead due to heap allocation that isn't necessary in the option case.

Comment: The only thing that's correct about this post is that many people (including OP, answers, and comments) misunderstood certain technical details about the underlying implementations of the optional or nullable types offered in one or both languages. As far as C# is concerned, the nullable of a struct (value type) is also a struct, which live on the stack (and are copied as needed). Anyone needing a reference to a struct should use the older route, which is to box it (casting to `object`), which can be done since the beginning days of C#, without the nullable support.

Comment: @rwong I mean, I don't claim anything contradictory anywhere, I say that languages with null have at best the same overhead as rust. Which is what you're saying.  I edited the part where I talk of heap allocation in nullable languages to avoid appearing to claim this

Answer (score 8):

Swift has a clever feature in the compiler: If “all bits zero” is not a valid value for type T, then the type optional uses all bits zero to represent nil. The most common use case are optional pointers, of course, followed by optional enums, where no case has all bits zero.

So no space overhead where it isn’t needed. And for something like optional, that cannot be done without overhead.

Comment: Others have mentioned that in fact `Option` **can** be implemented without overhead in most cases

Answer (score 5):

## In short: Language Pedigree

These languages draw inspiration from Haskell, which is a language built on principles of pure functional design and category theory. Haskell never had null in the first place, with that idea being represented with the `Maybe` type from the very beginning.

Scala in particular draws a lot of inspiration from Haskell while keeping null purely for interoperability with Java. It uses Option by convention rather than by design. It's a similar story for F#.

Although Rust has null pointers under the hood for bare metal work and foreign function interoperability, it opted to consider working with pointers `unsafe`, providing the Option type for that purpose in `safe` contexts. It's nothing more than a design choice that draws inspiration from Haskell. It happens to fit well with Rust's model of integrating lifetimes into its type system, so it seems like a natural design choice.

### Reminder: which approach is better varies by situation and preference

Whether Nullables or Options are better is a hotly debated issue among programming language enthusiasts. There is nothing objectively superior about Option types, just certain use cases it happens to excel at. Likewise for nullables; it's situational.

Both Options and Nullable types (with static analysis) solve the same problem, each with their own tradeoffs. In the best case, the two are identical in core function and performance. Options have the benefit of nesting, whereas Nullables are less verbose, have stronger performance guarantees, and tend to come with less complex type systems (potentially saving compilation time).

Comment: That does not answer the question "okay, old null pointers are better, but why do you need to introduce new `Option` type?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You *don't* need to introduce the Option type because there are other ways to get the same guarantees it offers surrounding null values. Some will argue that Option is more mathematically pure since it makes use of the type system instead of semantic analysis, but ultimately the effect is the same and it comes down to preference.

Comment: Simpler type system and simpler code (for many simple cases) are also benefits of tracking Nullability of types.

Comment: @ThomasW thanks for reminding me to mention verbosity.

Comment: Options are only more verbose in languages that add them after-the-fact. If a language is designed around options from the beginning (e.g. Swift) then they're just as concise as nullables.

Comment: @LambdaFairy In Swift's case, that only applies to safe navigation and null coalescence. You still have to declare variables verbosely and creation of optionals is verbose and explicit.

Comment: Beefster: var x: Int? declares an optional Int. If s is a String, then let x = Int(s) makes x an optional Int.

Comment: @gnasher729 I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, Options and nullable types are pretty similar. `Option<T>` and `T?` work pretty much the same. There are some differences like explicit `Some` and methods that operate on options. But you indicate that's not what you are interested in. Rather, you seem more interested in the implementation detail of using null pointers rather then some sort of enum.

In a language like Rust, nullable pointers wouldn't work, because Rust doesn't have the indirection of a language like Java.

In Java, an `ArrayList<String>` is actually a pointer to an `ArrayList` object which contains a pointer to a `String[]` which is a pointer to an array of pointers to `String` objects each of which contains a `char[]` which is a pointer to an array of chars.

In Rust, a `Vec<String>` contains a pointer to an array of `String` each of which contains a pointer to a `u8` array.

Consequently, in Rust, it is relatively rare that I want an `Option<&T>`. Most of the things that I want to have optional aren't references. For example, I often have an `Option<String>` but unlike in Java, `String` isn't a pointer to a `String`, it is a `String`.

Another way of looking at this, most types in Rust are value types not reference types. Thus nullable versions of those types couldn't be implemented as null pointers. They'd have to implemented as a value with a flag, which is how enums are implemented.

But the Rust compiler does have an optimization on this point. The easy case is `Option<&T>`, which can be implemented as a null pointer. But as noted, that's not actually very common. But the Rust compiler also looks inside the type to see if there is a non-nullable pointer inside. If compiling `Option<String>`, it see that `String` contains `Vec<u8>` which contains `RawVec<u8>` which contains `Unique<u8>` which contains `NonZero<*u8>`. The compiler knows that `NonZero` can never contain a null pointer, so it sets that field deep inside the String to null to indicate that the `Option` is `None`.

The consequence is that nullable pointer types wouldn't work for a language like Rust. Optional types with compiler optimization does.

Furthermore, this is a relatively obvious optimization. I suspect that all languages with optional types that care about performance will ensure it gets implemented as a null pointer when that is suitable. So, there is no performance reason to shy away from Optional types in favor of nullables.

Comment: What's in a name? Whether you call it Option or Nullable, None or null, it's the same beyond the verbiage. Though when called Nullable it is too often restricted to pointers (even if called references), and worse yet mandatory instead of optional.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I'm not really sure why you left that comment since my answer is all about the implementation strategy.

Comment: Nearly all is about the implementation-strategy, yes. But that small but important part isn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator, and that small part at the beginning points out they are basically the same, so I still have no idea what point you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable/nonnull pointers have very complicated semantics.

Let's say function f receives a nullable pointer as an argument, and wants to pass it to a function g which has a nonnull pointer. Obviously only if the pointer is not null. So g(p) gives a compile time error. What about "if (p != nil) g(p)"? That should work, but what is the difference? p is still a nullable pointer. So we need the compiler to be clever enough to know that after the if-statement, p cannot be null. So either you make massive changes in the compiler, or the feature is quite useless.

Now take optionals in Swift. How are they created?

First, there is a very general and very useful feature in Swift: enums with associated values. That means, for every case of an enum the programmer can define what values are stored in the enum value for that case. That feature is used to implement optionals: Optionals are just enums with two cases "none" and "some", where the "none" case has no associated data, and the "some" case does. Optionals are not even part of the language, they are implemented in the standard library.

What about "nil"? nil is a literal, similar to numeric or string literals. So nil is implemented in the compiler. nil is translated to a "NilConvertibleLiteral" (I'm probably spelling this wrong). In the standard library, where Optionals are implemented, the assignment operator and the equality / inequality operators are overloaded for the case that an operand is a "NilConvertibleLiteral" so optional == nil is implemented as "optional case is "none". It's all implemented in the Standard Library, except for the tiny bit in the compiler that knows how to compile "nil" just like it knows how to compile "13" or "3.1415e-20". And comparisons are defined in the standard library for all combinations of optionals and non-optionals: nil optionals are equal to nil optionals and not-equal to non-nil optionals, and two non-nil optionals compare their values. Nothing here in the compiler.

There are two bits of syntactic sugar: First, the ? and ! operators. Declaring a variable as T? or T! makes it an optional T. T?.x returns x if T is not nil, and nil if T is nil. T!.x returns x if T is not nil, and is *guaranteed* to crash if T is nil. In the example above, "g(p)" wouldn't compile because you can't use an optional where a non-optional is needed, "g(p!)" would compile and crash if p is nil, "if p != nil { g(p!) } cannot crash.

The other bit of syntactic sugar makes all the difference: "if let x = expression { ... } else { ... }. expression must be an optional value. If it is not nil, then the non-optional value is extracted and assigned to x, and the first list of statements is executed; if the expression is nil, the second list of statements is executed (optional). This combines checking whether an optional is nil with creating a non-optional value.

The advantages to nullable and non-null pointers: 1. It can be used for everything. Like a function converting a string to an integer returns an optional Int, so you write "if let i = Int(string) { success } else { failure }, and you can't avoid the test. 2. It has a very clean semantics. 3. It is not possible to avoid nil tests unless you use ! which can lead to a *guaranteed* crash (and ! means you're asking for it). 4. You actually cannot perform nil tests for non-optional values. Converting Objective-C to Swift I found lots of paranoid nil tests just disappearing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm late to the party here (and everyone is glowingly praising `Option`) but I'd like to point out that `Option` **comes with significant downsides** for maintainability.

This is a re-hash of Clojure author Rich Hickey's discussion of maybe types here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR5WdGrpoug

While not as bad a untyped null references,

### Option types are a 500 million dollar mistake

#### Starting at the beginning

There are 3 ways of handling nullability:

**First:** the billion dollar mistake. A reference can be null but this fact is not encoded in the type system.

This is what Java does. Anytime you receive a pointer to something you don't know whether or not it is pointing to an actual object or null.

```java
string foo(String x) {
  // this might work or it might throw a null pointer exception
  return x.substring(0, 1);
}

// both of these invocations are allowed by the compiler
// however one will fail at runtime.
foo(null);
foo("xyz");
```

**Second:** Null references exist but the type system understands that fact and forces the programmer to specify when null is expected and when it is not expected.

This is how TypeScript handles null.

```js
function foo(x: string): string {
    return x.substr(0, 2);
}


foo(null); // You cannot write this in TypeScript as x was not declared as being nullable.
foo("sdf"); // works fine

function relaxedFoo(x?: string): string {
  if (x != null) // compiler forces you to check for null
    return x.substr(0, 1);
  return '';
}

relaxedFoo(null); // works fine. We indicated to the compiler that relaxedFoo can handle null references
```

**Third**:

The `Option`/ `Maybe` type. This "removes" null altogether. The easiest way to think about this is that rather than having a thing that is null or not null, now you have a collection that is empty or not empty. `Option` has already been discussed at great length in the other answers here.

### `Option` -- the 500 million dollar mistake

So what is so bad about `Option` that I'd spend an hour on Sunday morning writing about it?

It has to do with program maintenance.

#### Relaxing Requirements

Take a look at the following code:

```
function foo(x: string): string {...}
```

`foo` requires all callers to always pass a string. But what if tomorrow I want to relax that constraint? Callers can call me with a string or without.

If I used `Option` I'd end up here:

```
function foo(x: Option<string>): string {...}
```

which breaks all callers as `Option<string>` in not compatible with `string`.

Callers doing `foo('sdf');` must be updated to `foo(Option('sdf'));`. Pretty problematic if this is a library released publicly.

However, this isn't an issue in TypeScript and other languages that understand null references. In those languages I would do:

```
function foo(x: ?string): string {...}
```

`?string` is a union type of `string` and `null`, thus no existing callers break. I can release an update to my library and not break any of its consumers.

```
foo('sdf'); // requires no change as 'sdf' is allowed in the type union of `null | string`
```

The same problem with `Option` also exists in the reverse -- when making return types provide stronger guarantees.

I.e.,

Changing `foo(): Option<string>` to `foo(): string` shouldn't be considered a breaking change.

Of course `foo(): string` to `foo(): Option<string>` is breaking (and should be breaking) since a new type is added.

Comment: If you change a function type from an optional string to just a string, then you have changed the semantics of the function (because how are missing values now represented? Where did they go?). So you *want* clients to break, since they are now relying on obsolete semantics. It is just as if you changed the return value from a string to an integer - you *want* clients to stop compiling, this is the whole point of a statically typed language.

Comment: @JacquesB - you completely misunderstood the answer.

If you could return null but now no longer return null, there is no need to check for null.

Here is a more thorough explanation by Clojure author Rich Hickey: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR5WdGrpoug

Comment: @mlaw He's right. If `null` means absence of value, for example, why do you suddenly sure you'll get a value? I understand your mind, but don't agree.

Comment: @mlaw: No but the code which do check for null is now wrong since the value is never null. This should be a compile time error.

Comment: Is it really worth the cost to break callers that check for an impossible null when checking for an impossible null is, essentially, a no-op? It is a huge cost to clients that consume a library to do this.

Comment: @mlaw: Of course you should remove the dead code! The cost of this is minuscule compared to the maintenance nightmare of letting dead code and meaningless checks proliferate in a code base. Bottom line is that if you change the contract of a function, you will have to update the clients. If you don't want to change the clients then don't change the contract.

Comment: @JacquesB well how about the reverse then -- function arguments. I think we can at least find agreement here.

Relaxing an argument from `string` to `Option<string>` shouldn't break callers. Calls of `foo('sdf')` are all already semantically and syntactically correct, even under the relaxed constraint. `?string` types (rather than `Option<string>`) allow this sort of relaxing of requirements on function arguments without breaking callers.

Comment: @mlaw But how about in the return type? Changing a return type from string to Option<string> there is a breaking change. Its Option<string> to string that is the non-breaking change. Why should null be special? Option and explicit nullable references are mostly isomorphic apart from the fact that explicit nullable references are an exception in the typesystem, so can't be used with the rest of the language as cleanly.

Comment: @user1937198 - yes. I agree. String to Option<string> on return is and should be a breaking change. But the reverse -- Option<string> to String on a return type should not be considered a breaking change -- as no caller would actually break.

Comment: @mlaw and thats a bunch of rules to memorize. Alternatively you can generalize it with something like C++'s conversion operators, and allow an Option<T> to implicitly be constructed from a T, and allow any other appropriate type to do the same. Or you can take rusts view and say all conversions must be explicit.

Comment: @mlaw Why should you be able to expand it to take an Option type, but not a Result or a List? Either is as much a relaxing of a constraint. Why is the nullability constraint special enough that its the one you should be allowed to relax?

Comment: @mlaw: You can apply the same reasoning to lists. If a function expects a list of strings but is supplied a single string as argument, would you want the language to implicitly convert the single string argument into a list with one element? I wouldn't, I would prefer the compiler to flag this as type error.

Comment: @JacquesB Yeah, maybe collections should be able to be relaxed too  :) Thats essentially variadic args.

I think a lot of these things should be done. Take Scala for example. It uses the same syntax for array access and method calls -- allowing you to convert a variable back and forth between an array or function pointer and not break callers.

Comment: @JacquesB In C# it is a source compatible change to convert the last argument of a function to a params argument, converting it into an array of one element. And thats a differenet set of rules.

Comment: @mlaw It is a choice in the language. Its not really something you can say is better or worse. Some like Haskell and Rust value uniformity of the type system and think it should be definable as a user type. Some like having null as a special case. Its not really anything other than an opinion that one is better than the other.

Comment: The only static language that really has an answer to generalized relaxing of constraints is C++ with its implicit conversions system. And I'm not sure thats really the best option.

Comment: @user1937198 - I'm trying to point out that there's a cost to these choices.

There's a cost to a language not allowing you to make non-breaking changes (like changing ?string to string for a function argument)

Comment: @mlaw And theres a cost to allowing it. The tone of this answer doesn't seem to cover that.